# bcp to generate a file into an ftp site

Tags: sql-server

I have a job that runs every night to generate a file on my server.

```
 declare @cmd varchar (4000)
 set @cmd = 'bcp "select * from databasename.dbo.viewname" queryout C:\FolderName\' +  convert(varchar, getdate(), 112) + '_'+ substring(convert(varchar, getdate(), 114),1,2)+  substring(convert(varchar, getdate(), 114),4,2) +  '_FileName.txt -t^; -T -c'

EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @cmd
```

Now, I want to generate the file directly into an ftp site.

Because it seems to be impossible using only a bcp commande, I used the following script to do it. (I test it on 2 different ftp sites)

```
DECLARE @FTPServer varchar(128)
DECLARE @FTPUser varchar(128)
DECLARE @FTPPwd varchar(128)
DECLARE @SourcePath varchar(128)
DECLARE @SourceFiles varchar(128)
DECLARE @DestPath varchar(128)
DECLARE @FTPMode varchar(10)

-- FTP attributes.
SET @FTPServer = 'MyftpDomain'
SET @FTPUser = 'Mylogin'
SET @FTPPwd = 'MyPwd'
SET @SourcePath = 'C:\ftp'
SET @SourceFiles = 'test.txt'
SET @DestPath = 'files' 
SET @FTPMode = 'binary' 

DECLARE @cmd varchar(1000)
DECLARE @workfile varchar(128)
DECLARE @nowstr varchar(25)

-- Get the %TEMP% environment variable.
DECLARE @tempdir varchar(128)
CREATE TABLE #tempvartable(info VARCHAR(1000))
INSERT #tempvartable EXEC master..xp_cmdshell 'echo %temp%'
SET @tempdir = (SELECT top 1 info FROM #tempvartable)
IF RIGHT(@tempdir, 1) <> '\' SET @tempdir = @tempdir + '\'
DROP TABLE #tempvartable

-- Generate @workfile
SET @nowstr = replace(replace(convert(varchar(30), GETDATE(), 121), ' ', '_'), ':', '-')
SET @workfile = 'FTP_SPID' + convert(varchar(128), @@spid) + '_' + @nowstr + '.txt'

-- Deal with special chars for echo commands.
select @FTPServer = replace(replace(replace(@FTPServer, '|', '^|'),'<','^<'),'>','^>')
select @FTPUser = replace(replace(replace(@FTPUser, '|', '^|'),'<','^<'),'>','^>')
select @FTPPwd = replace(replace(replace(@FTPPwd, '|', '^|'),'<','^<'),'>','^>')
select @DestPath = replace(replace(replace(@DestPath, '|', '^|'),'<','^<'),'>','^>')
IF RIGHT(@SourcePath, 1) <> '\' SET @SourcePath = @SourcePath + '\'

-- Build the FTP script file.
select @cmd = 'echo ' + 'open ' + @FTPServer + ' > ' + @tempdir + @workfile
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @cmd
select @cmd = 'echo ' + @FTPUser + '>> ' + @tempdir + @workfile
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @cmd
select @cmd = 'echo ' + @FTPPwd + '>> ' + @tempdir + @workfile
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @cmd
select @cmd = 'echo ' + 'prompt ' + ' >> ' + @tempdir + @workfile
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @cmd
IF LEN(@FTPMode) > 0
BEGIN
    select @cmd = 'echo ' + @FTPMode + ' >> ' + @tempdir + @workfile
    EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @cmd
END
IF LEN(@DestPath) > 0
BEGIN
    select @cmd = 'echo ' + 'cd ' + @DestPath + ' >> ' + @tempdir + @workfile
    EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @cmd
END
select @cmd = 'echo ' + 'put ' + @SourcePath + @SourceFiles + ' >> ' + @tempdir + @workfile
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @cmd
select @cmd = 'echo ' + 'quit' + ' >> ' + @tempdir + @workfile
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @cmd

-- Execute the FTP command via script file.
select @cmd = 'ftp -s:' + @tempdir + @workfile
create table #a (id int identity(1,1), s varchar(1000))
insert #a
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @cmd
select id, ouputtmp = s from #a

-- Clean up.
drop table #a
select @cmd = 'del ' + @tempdir + @workfile
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @cmd
```

1/I tried first to do it from local pc. So I generate the file and then execute the script in order to put the file into the ftp.

It works!!!!

1.1/ I tried to do it directly from the cmd window (dos)

```
+ open  : OK
+ login : OK
+ password : OK
+ bin : OK
+ put : OK
```

It works !!!

2/2.1/I tried to do the same thing on another ftp site and also it works from either the script or the cmd window (dos)!!!

The problem occurs when I tried to do it from my distant server where I have the licence of sqlserver:

So, I tried to do the same from my Microsoft Azure server where I have my MS Sql Server. It didn't works to none of the two ftp sites with none of the 2 methods (script and cmd window)

When I tried to put the file using the script on the first ftp It generates the following error:

```
Illegal PORT command.
```

and using the cmd window it generates:

```
 500 Illegal PORT command.
 425 Use PORT or PASV first
```

Notice that on this first ftp, the active transfer mode is enable

On the second ftp,where the default transfer mode is enable,
when I tried to put the file using the script, the script run without stopping (never finished).

And using the cmd window, when I enter the put commande, I get :

```
200 port command successfull
150 opening data channel for file upload to server of "filepath"
```

Can anyone help me to understand the source of the problem and how can I avoid it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you saying the example works ok but storing into somewhere else doesn't work? Does the userid the SQL Server is running on have rights to write there?

Comment: I have all rights to write on the ftp. But I don't know the way how should I mentionned the ftp path. Maybe we should put also all the connection parameters

Comment: Are you trying to write the file directly into ftp server using ftp protocol using bcp? I don't think that's possible, but if there's windows file share you could use \\server\share\path\file -style as the path?

Comment: And of course you could write the file into the database server and then transfer the file with separate command using xp_cmdshell

Comment: Hello James.. could you help me if you please to understand the problem. Thanks in adv

Comment: So it looks like you would need passive mode FTP for the connection to work  from Azure. I would assume you can’t change the firewall in any way or install 3rd party applications for the transfer? I don't really know what libraries etc. are available in azure, maybe you should open new question for the passive ftp  from azure?